# Still Show Added Product under Related Products after adding to cart in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list

Is anyone familiar with this. I have noticed that after I add a product to cart, it disappears in my list of related products. What I want is to still show that specific product even if I already added it to cart.

I think it's a default Magento feature that after adding an item to cart, it disappears under the related products of a specific product.

Can I do this easily via Magento admin? Or do I need to modify a core code or template file? I hope some Magento expert can guide me to the right direction. O_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related` and from the method `_prepareData` remove this:

```
        Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
        );
```

Comment: I have override the code but not working got this error "Invalid method Vendor_RelatedProductBlock_Block_Product_List_Related::canEmailToFriend(Array
(
)
)"